# Adding UISearchController to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to add a `UIViewSearchController` to ad `UIView` however it does not seem to show? So far I've created a subclass of `UISearchController` and `UISearchBar`. I've done that to remove the cancel button, from the searchController. However since i added these custom classes the searchBar does not show in the View? How come this that?

**viewDidLoad in viewcontroller**

```
    //SearchController
    backSearchView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = MySearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, self.view.frame.width-16, 44)
        controller.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)

        controller.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Søg"
        controller.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Default
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = controller.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.clipsToBounds = true
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.layer.cornerRadius = 1
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        backSearchView.addSubview(controller.searchBar)



        return controller
    })()
```

**SearchController subclass**

```
class MySearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

        lazy var customSearchBar: NoCancelSearchBar = {
            [unowned self] in
            let result = NoCancelSearchBar(frame:CGRectZero)
            result.delegate = self
            return result
            }()

        override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
            get {
                return customSearchBar
            }
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

**SearchBar subclass**

```
class NoCancelSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.showsCancelButton = false
    }

}
```